# What is meant by 'not my cup of tea'?

Tags: meaning, idioms

I am new to English. I don't know what is meaning of it and also I don't know where to use ‘not my cup of tea’ and in which situation.

I read this sentence in one website

> Looking at old paintings is not my cup of tea.

Could you please tell me what it means and when I should use it.

Answer (score 8):

**'not my cup of tea'** is an idiom - if something is not your cup of tea, you do not like it or you are not interested in it. There is also a positive version of this expression, 'it's my cup of tea', used to describe something you like.

For example:

> Listening to heavy metal music isn’t really my cup of tea.

It would be considered a British english expression, and is synonymous with the more American expression '*not up my alley*'

> Listening to heavy metal music isn’t really up my alley.

Comment: "It would be considered a British english expression" might be incorrect. I asked about it on Reddit and the answers there indicate that it is a common expression rather than being specific to British English. Reddit link: https://www.reddit.com/r/EnglishLearning/comments/9yib1y/not_my_cup_of_tea/

Answer (score 1):

This means that they do not enjoy looking at old paintings.  See [My cup of tea](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/my-cup-of-tea.html)